# How can i get the android back button to close the app everytime the home button is clicked?

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android development. I am facing a problem with fragments. Initially, anytime i opened a fragment and hit the back button on the android device, it closes the app until i found a solution which involved the use of fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null) method; but my problem is that if i open other fragments from the home fragment and click the home button each time i opened a new fragment, the back button, keeps going back to the previous fragment even after it gets to the home fragment. To explain further lets assume this are my events on the app.

app opens => Home fragment => fragment B => Home fragment => fragment c => fragment D =>Home fragment

when i hit the back button this is what it does:

Home fragment => fragment D => fragment c => Home fragment => fragment B => Home fragment => app closes

I don't like the fact that even after hitting the home fragment, the app continues going back to the fragments before the home fragment.

Please how can i make sure that every time the user gets to the home fragment and presses the back button it cancels all other fragments before it and just closes the app.

I hope i explained this well. please any help would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide relevant code man. Also, a shot in the dark, why not remove `addToBackstack` from the transaction where you're adding the home fragment. So it shan't be in the backstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always beware of coding an app that bucks the Android Framework...

Clear Fragment stack:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, 
FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Clear Activity stack:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Your_Current_Activity.this, 
Your_Destination_Activity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK 
|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: clearing the activity did exactly what i needed. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with these two methods in your activity -

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: this is not working. It shuts down the app completely when the home fragment button is pressed.